# Size classes and auto layout for iOS development

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, size-classes

I am trying to create a simple UI that works on all devices (obviously) and I haven't had much success. The program consists of two labels, a button, an image view and a textfield, I am also using a universal storyboard.

I implemented a top constraint, horizontally centred and fixed the width and height for all labels, buttons and textfields. The only exception I made with the image view was that instead of implementing a top constraint, I used a bottom one instead as I have found that utilising the former would result in it being only partially displayed. I would then switch from the universal storyboard to one with base values. From their I would delete the existing constraints and add new ones after moving the UI elements to their new locations on the different sized screen.

When I run my app on an iPhone 4S, the layout, whilst mostly correct, is still not perfect (i.e. a label is far too close to the image). Does anyone know how I can make my layouts look correct? I have been following this guide, [Adaptive Layout Tutorial in iOS 9](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Thanks so much for your help!

[Example of the constraints for the picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXMP.png)

Comment: Please break your post into paragraphs so it's easier to understand, and maybe include screenshots instead of explaining the constraints. This will help us give you a better answer and faster. Also, I suggest you skip the part where you say you are new to Swift, that information is irrelevant to us.

Comment: Hi Emilio, Thanks for your advice! I have updated my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how familiar are you with autolayout, therfore I'd suggest you watch [Stanford university lecture regarding autolayout](https://youtu.be/pv1EHGEf884?t=38m53s).

In short, according to the lecture and after looking at your picture, you should almost never set constraints with actual numbers. Use "Standart value" and when you can't choose "Standart value" write 0.

I'd recommend watching the above lecture and the rest of the examples in there.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your label has 2 problematic constraints 
1. Top space (30 points) to "how old is your dog"
2. Top space (28 points) to button

That means that your button is 2 points height (really small!!)
Or - because the button has already a fixed height, the label and the text field are too close (and maybe even overlaps the button)
You should delete the top space constrain (to "How old is your dog") and do something else, or give it more points height

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Yitschak, just to get this straight, you're saying that I should delete the height constraint from the label to the text field? I don't really understand how this will help my problem. I am having trouble with getting the label "Your dog is..." to maintain the intended height that I have set it. I will update my original comment to show the constraints for the picture. After taking a look, it would be great if you could tell me the issue. Thanks so much!